# How to unbind non-custom events in a jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, plugins, destroy

I'm doing a plugin and I have a few events like this one:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(event) {
    _plugin.methodCall();
});
```

Also a `$(document).on('click', function(){});` event. How do I unbind these in my destroy function without messing other user-defined events?

Or is it better to get creative with custom events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [jQuery .off](http://api.jquery.com/off/) in combination with namespaces when attaching event with `".on"`

```
    var validate = function() {
          // Code to validate form entries
        };

        // Delegate events under the ".validator" namespace
        $( "form" ).on( "click.validator", "button", validate );

        $( "form" ).on( "keypress.validator", "input[type='text']", validate );

        // Remove event handlers in the ".validator" namespace
        $( "form" ).off( ".validator" );
```

Comment: So basically change my events from 'load resize' to 'load.something resize.something' and then .off('.something') ?

Comment: Yes, for example you can use your plugin name

Comment: Jeez, if only I knew it were so easy. Thanks!